# IK rig jittering

Tags: rigging

I stumbled upon a very annoying issue that prevents me from advancing with my project.
I designed a robotic arm with multiple joints where each joint rotates in different axis. After connecting an IK constraint, setting the chain length and lock IK axies for certain joints the IK target wobbles whole construction and it looks like its hasitating in which direction it should bend. Maybe somebody here knows the answer.

[image: Rig starting position]

[image: Bone structure]

[Example GIF#1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k0_UoDeN8ITRpukXGhKg-j9PXvnwTpkJ/view?usp=sharing)

[Example GIF#2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IbEQ5sQB3zbKKkYz6vBMkuk2S5_Ij2PX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello, it may be a circular dependency (a parent is influenced by a child bone through a constraint for example), but maybe share your armature? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: IK target is unparented. Sure, here you go! https://pasteall.org/blend/e2dfa5c2d70a4a099d4678ae95d6df3b

Comment: First thing maybe in Edit mode put the Ik target at the tail of the IK so that once you switch from Edit to Pose mode the IK doesn't jump to the head of the target. As for the wobble it must be due to the fact that your IK doesn't have any Pole Target so at one point it switch from a direction to another, whereas if you gave a Pole Target it would always bend in its direction

Comment: I tried adding a pole target, but when I do it my starting joint ignores axis lock ( I want it only to rotate in z axis) and rotates wherever it wants :(

Comment: Is it what you want? https://zupimages.net/up/22/17/0nqf.gif

Comment: Close, but notice how first bone acts (it should rotate only on z axis - check GIF images I provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have a set-up with a lot of axis locks, this situation may occur. At a certain position you can reach a point where bone cannot be moved in the current way:

[image]

If we move bone farther, IK bone no longer can reach its target, but Blender finds the way how to reach it if the bone rotations organized in different way:

[image]

You see, then Blender builds the animation it does not rely on previous frames. It is important to get any frame directly from scratch, so that you have same result either from playback or scrolling in timeline or rendering animation on several render farms.

So to fix that - try to reduce rules in IK, or avoid positions that may lead to these situations.

If removing limits still doesn't help - try to set up initial positions to chain bones, so Blender doesn't move them far away:

[image]

Comment: I noticed that my rig consisted too few joints and blender IK algorythm couldn't handle it. I learned it hard way, by posing it as FK...